# Is $\mathcal{O}_q(GL_n(k))$ a Nichols algebra?

Tags: quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $k$ be a field. The quantized coordinate ring of the group $GL_n(k)$ is defined in Section 3.1 in [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0211306v1.pdf). Is $\mathcal{O}_q(GL_n(k))$ a [Nichols algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichols_algebra)? Thank you very much.